# Kernel-Mode Driver Development in Windows

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, dma

I'm developing a new Kernel-Mode driver, that should run on Windows 10 (64-bit).

This driver should allocate 48GB of ***continuous physical*** memory, and map it (its base address) to a virtual address in the user space of the Windows application that will use it. The system actually has 64GB of RAM installed on it, so it might be needed to make a segment of the memory dedicated for this use, perhaps by changing a boot entry information.

In addition, the driver should reveal its base address somehow to an FPGA-based device, located on the PCIe slot. The purpose of this, is to use this 48GB of continuous physical allocated memory, as a DMA (Direct Memory Access). Namely, the FPGA-based device will generate data, and write it at the appropriate location in the DMA. The host software will try to read from that location, in a cyclic fashion. That is, the FPGA will override the data in the buffer, and the host will try to keep the pace, and read that data before it is overridden.

Please note that this question only deals with the host side (the driver), and not with the FPGA side.

So, basically my questions are:

1. How do I make such an allocation (as described above)?
2. How do I map the base address from the virtual address in the Kernel-Space, to the appropriate virtual address in the User-Space?
3. How do I reveal that base address to the FPGA (located on the PCIe slot), so it will know where to perform its write operations?
4. What other Callback-Functions should this driver implement, in terms of events handling?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not expert on the subject, but it seems to me that this question may get put on hold as too broad. In general you should ask only one specific question at the time to make it easier to answer. Please [edit] your question and try to increase focus on specific area, and remove parts that aren't necessary or can be asked separately.

Comment: **1.** use or `MmAllocateContiguousMemorySpecifyCache` or (better for you) [`MmAllocatePagesForMdlEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554489) with `MM_ALLOCATE_REQUIRE_CONTIGUOUS_CHUNKS` flag (win7+). **2.** [`MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554629(v=vs.85).aspx) with *AccessMode=UserMode* - *

The routine returns a user address that is valid in the context of the process in which the driver is running*

Comment: in case use [`MmAllocateContiguousMemorySpecifyCache`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554464(v=vs.85).aspx) you will be need then allocate space for *MDL* call `MmInitializeMdl` (macro) and [`MmBuildMdlForNonPagedPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554498(v=vs.85).aspx) finally

Comment: You can look at [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) and [VirtualCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee483154.aspx). VirtualCopy is accessible only from the driver mode and allows you to map the virtual address to some fixed physical address. In your case, the application can call VirtualAlloc and pass the virtual address to the driver. The driver can then map it to a fixed physical address and pass it to the FPGA. Finally you will have to pin these pages.